# Django-recurrence widget not working without staff permissions

Tags: python, django

The superuser can access the widget and use it fine but a user which signed up using the website can't, when they click on it nothing happens.

I've tried all the other solutions on here but nothing works including adding form.media using the JavaScript catalogue.

Forms.py:

```py
class RecurringAbsencesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RecurringAbsences
        fields = ['ID','Recurrences']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
    
    class Media:
        js = ('/admin/jsi18n', '/admin/js/core.js',)
```

HTML:

```html
{% extends 'Base.html' %}
{% load bulma_tags %}
{% block title %}Create Recurring Absence{% endblock %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
    {{form.media}}
</head>


<div class="main container column is-3">
    <h1 class="title has-text-centered"> Create Recurring Absence </h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="container has-text-weight-bold">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if message %}
            {% include "messages.html" %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ form }}
            
            {{ form.media }}
            {% for error in form.errors %}
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="pt-6 pb-3">
                {{ form2 | bulma }}
            </div>
            
            <button id="submit" type="submit" class="button is-fullwidth is-link">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

`form` is the recurrence form widget

Included in Urls.py
`url(r'^jsi18n', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), js_info_dict),`

Comment: You sure you need the `/admin` prefix in those static urls in the form media? That would always end up matching an admin url which is staff protected?

Comment: @user2390182 getting rid of those doesn't fix it but makes it so the issues is for everyone, i might need to add these files in a path that isnt behind admin